# How do parcels relate to United States Census hierarchy?

Tags: data, united-states, census, parcel

The United States Census Bureau operates on the [Standard Hierarchy of Census Geographic Entities](https://www2.census.gov/geo/pdfs/reference/geodiagram.pdf), which ranges from NATION (n=1) to Census Blocks (n=8.1 million as of 2022).

It is my understanding 'parcel' datasets, such as this one, typically offers a *smaller* geographic entities than the Census Blocks. Commercial data products, such as REGRID, claims that their data describes more than '152 million' parcels across the United States.

How, if at all, do 'parcels' relate to the United States Census hierarchy?

Are parcels maintained by the United States Census Bureau or are parcels a function of local governments?

Comment: If this is open data then I think the place to ask about how it is compiled is at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Parcels aren't part of the Census hierarchy.